# JSP page is not parsed and not rendered properly

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on spring web flow project. But my jspx file wasn't renderd into html properly. Did I miss some library?
Please help!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jsp:root 
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
        version="2.0">
<jsp:directive.page language="java"
contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" />
<jsp:text>
    <![CDATA[ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> ]]>
</jsp:text>
<jsp:text>
    <![CDATA[ <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> ]]>
</jsp:text>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Start View</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is the first page of the flow, the Start View.</p>
These are the current entries:<br/>
<form method="post">
    <ul>
        <c:forEach items="${theResultList}" var="item">
            <li>
                ${item}
            </li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" name="_eventId_toFirst" value="Retrieve Entries"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
</jsp:root>
```

And this is rended code in html

```
<!--

?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?

-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>

            This is the first page of the flow, the Start View…

        </p>


            These are the current entries:

        <br></br>
        <form method="post">
            <ul>
                ***<c:foreach items="[Ljava.lang.String;@63664f8b" var="item"></c:foreach>***
            </ul>
            <input type="submit" name="_eventId_toFirst" value="Retrieve Entries"></input>
        </form>
    </body>
```

The tag "forEach" wasn't rended.

Below is my pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ivan.springwebflowtut</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringWebFlowTutorial</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringWebFlowTutorial Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <springwf.version>2.0.9.RELEASE</springwf.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ognl</groupId>
      <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.9</version>
    </dependency>

   <!--  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsoure.org.jboss.el</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.GA</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-el-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>${springwf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
        <version>${springwf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 <!--    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.webflow</artifactId>
        <version>${springwf.version}</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <!-- Build-time dependencies -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test-time dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringWebFlowTutorial</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Change source and target elements to 1.7 -->
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Post your web.xml and Spring Controller logic

Comment: Are you sure your {theResultList} returns list of strings. If the item itself is an object you should print it using dot eg item.name

Comment: Is there no compilation error message?

Comment: Is the output got edited? The 3* and the c:foreach is not the same case (forEach) as in the source?